# Select query taking too long in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have table with following `create statement`

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `workname` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `setup_dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `setup_new_dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `check_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_id` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workstat` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `a_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workstat2` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

My select query is `select * from table`

My select query is taking quite a long time to execute.
What changes (such as indexing) can i make in the table to make sure that select queries are no more slow.

Is it taking long because of ``data`longtext COLLATE utf8_bin`
Can I do some indexing to resolve this slowness?

When I do `explain` in front of query I get following output

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'table1', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '8756', NULL
```

Comment: What is "quite a long time" for you? It would be helpful to see the select query, which you have used.

Comment: Can you add  your select statement to your question? Also, put "explain" in front of the select statement and execute that, paste that output.

Comment: @Crutches I have updated my question with all details asked by you. Please help me out here

Comment: How much data do you currently have on that table and what is the time it is taking. Is the server in cloud, or in your local machine?

Comment: @all_techie it really depends on the amount of data in there. what are you storing in the data field? Since you can store up to 4 GB in a LONGTEXT field, this could explain the long fetch time.

Comment: The server is in my local machine. It takes around 20-30 seconds to run the select query. The other select queries on other tables in the same database are fast and works fine. I have issue only with this table

Comment: Why do you need ALL data from the table? did you try to apply any `WHERE` condition? or to request only some particular columns but not `*`?